# Magento 2.3: category image gets overwritten

Tags: magento2.3, image-upload, upload, category-image

I came across an unexpected behaviour in Magento 2.3 Adminhtml area.
Uploading an image with the same name of another already present in the upload category folder replaces the old the one with new uploaded one.
I thought that the new one was renamed example: "same_name_1.jpg", but this does not happen.

Anyone is experiencing this behaviour? Should I change some settings in the backend?

Comment: which specific admin area you experience this issue?

Comment: sorry, I did not specify it. It’s in the edit category section

Comment: I have tried also in my local machine, it only rewrites on `tmp>catalog` during upload of images but after save, the image will as is and when you try to upload the same image with the same name and the same size it will retain the current image but if you upload with the same name but different size it will overwrite

Comment: yes am facing same issue

Answer (score 3):

this Magento 2.3.3 default issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25099

For fixed issue please installed this module

https://github.com/FutureActivities/Magento-Fix-Category-Images